# How can i animate helicopter blades?

Tags: animation, parent

Chopper with blades added,after positioning correctly, because of pasting it from another file with it flat
[image]
The propeller blades
[image]

I made a helicopter with separate propeller blades acting as a child to the helicopter. I made the rotation animation with the blades in another blender file with them flat then copied the propeller blades and animation from that file and connected to the helicopter as parent/child. However, when i position the blade with its animation data to the helicopter it goes flat and doesn't stay where i positioned because i animated it flat. So i end up with a lop sided propeller blade as the helicopter is at an angle.

The helicopter itself is already animated so i am adding the blades last which has made it more difficult. Is there an easy way to animate the blades so i can easily add to helicopter? I've tried doing it with the helicopter in motion and its very difficult.

Comment: If the rotor child of the helicopter it will follow it. You have to animate only the rotation of it.

Comment: Does the helicopter had the rotation applied? What happens if you select the helicopter and press ALT+R. Then the helicopter should be aligned to the global grid. If not then the two objects have different orientations.